# Expression<Func<T, bool>> method argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, delegates, expression

I'm trying to make a generic method that returns the string version of an expression:

```
public string GetExpressionString(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr) where T: class
{
    return exp.Body.ToString();
}
```

`Cannot resolve symbol T`

Works well if I change `T` to a hard coded type.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to declare `T` as a generic type parameter on the method:

```
public string GetExpressionString<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp)
    where T: class
{
    return exp.Body.ToString();
}

// call like this
GetExpressionString<string>(s => false);
GetExpressionString((Expression<Func<string, bool>>)(s => false));
```

Or on the parent class:

```
public class MyClass<T>
    where T: class
{
    public string GetExpressionString(Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp)
    {
        return exp.Body.ToString();
    }
}

// call like this
var myInstance = new MyClass<string>();
myInstance.GetExpressionString(s => false);
```

**Further Reading:**

- [Generic Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

It's a syntax error. You haven't declared T as a generic type argument

```
public string GetExpressionString<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr) where T: class
{
    return exp.Body.ToString();
}
```

notice the `<T>`